# How to log the latest git commit hash in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, jar, git-commit

I am new to Git. I have developed an app in Java. The app logs every information in a text file during the execution. I have committed the application using Git. Now I want to print the latest Git commit hash value in the log file.

E.g.: Inside **mysteps.log** file:

Start of logging...

[image]

Please instruct me how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("git rev-parse HEAD");
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())
)) {
    String revision = reader.readLine();
    // log the revision here
}
```

**Attention: Don't use this code in production.** It is environment dependent which means that it will fail in case if Git is not installed or context is not in git repository.

To be able to use it in production you have to patch the revision into your artifact (eg. into `jar` archive). Usually it is done as a part of automated build by a build system (eg. gradle, maven, ant). For instance during maven build you might create new file with git-hash and pack it into the jar, then during runtime you can read the file whenever you need.